# Why a single paren in vector norm notation?

Tags: notation, normed-spaces

I am reading Goodfellow-Bengio-Courville *Deep Learning* book, and right at the beginning (chapter 1, where they go over basic Linear algebra concepts) they use this notation to define a vector norm:

$$
\| x\|_p = \left. \sum_i |x_i|^p \right)^{1/p}
$$

the meaning is clear, and the notation is what I would have expected, except for the single closing parenthesis. Any special meaning? I am not familiar with this convention.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I haven't looked at that book, but this looks to me like an open parenthesis was omitted due to a typographical error

Comment: I'd say either a typographical error or a rendering error.

Comment: In [this version](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/linear_algebra.html) on page 37, there is an open parenthesis

Comment: @J.W.Tanner there seems to be a closed parenthesis in the page you linked

Comment: I see open and closed parentheses there

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it comes down to providing errata for a particular text, and is therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no special meaning to the unmatched closed parenthesis there.

For some reason, you are not seeing the open parenthesis,

but it is there in this [online version](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/linear_algebra.html) on page 37, equation 2.30.

Comment: Ah, ok. Probably just a typo in the version I'm reading (which is just a download of the online pdf,  not the actual printed version). I must have downloaded an earlier version

Answer (score 1):

An opening parenthesis has definitely been omitted in a typo. This formula is the standard definition of the $L^p$ norm; even the left-hand side is its usual symbol.